# should jena's rdf connection remote be singleton or prototype?

Tags: rdf, jena

I'm using apache jena with a remote fuseki server. And with spring support. I want to know whether rdf connection remote should be singleton or prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RDFConnection` when remote is a single connection to the database (over HTTP) and can be used either way.  It is thread-safe.

It is lightweight - so unless you have identifed special needs, the pattern shown at http://jena.apache.org/documentation/rdfconnection/ is preferable.